# Split string, and take substring

Tags: postgresql

Let's say I have a name: Marco Peter Hanson

From this name, I just want to show Initials, like This:  M.P.H

How can I do this? I tried with `substr` and `split_part`, but can't seem to get it right.

```
substr(comments, 1, 1)
```

will give me the letter "M", and

```
split_part(comments, ' ', 3)
```

will give me "Hanson"

I feel like I should put both substr and split_part to work together?

The name can also just be Marco Peter, which then should give M.P, but it can also be several more names like: Maro Peter Hanson Brad, which then should give M.P.H.B.

So I need to do something like: `split_part(comments, ' ', comments.length)` instead of hardcoding the length of the "comments"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `string_agg` like this, assuming your table is named `People` and the column with names is comment, here is how you can modify the query to work with your table -->

```
SELECT 
        People.id, -- Assuming there's an id column
        string_agg(substr(word, 1, 1), '.') AS initials
    FROM 
        People,
        unnest(string_to_array(People.comment, ' ')) AS word
    GROUP BY 
        People.id;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. I don't understand how use it to select from the table. Say I have a table called "People", and I want to select the "comment". How would you do that in your code? And also without hardcoding "Marco Peter Hanson", but using "comment" instead, as the table will have many entries"